# Java でオブジェクトの clone() をした際に HashMap のメンバのディープコピーができません

Tags: java

メンバに HashMap を含むオブジェクトのクローンを生成した際に、HashMap だけがディープコピーできていません。
ArrayList のメンバも含んでいるのですが、そちらはディープコピーできています。

どちらも新しいインスタンスを代入しているのですが...

どこか間違っていますでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

クローンするクラス

```
public class Progression implements Serializable, Cloneable {

    @PrimaryKey public long progressionId;
    public List<DegreeNotation> degreeNotations;
    public Map<Integer, Interval> modulations;
    public List<Function> functions;
    public List<String> tags;
    public List<String> notes;

    public Progression() {
        progressionId = System.currentTimeMillis();
        degreeNotations = new ArrayList<>();
        modulations = new HashMap<>();
        tags = new ArrayList<>();
        notes = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public Map<Integer, Interval> getModulations() {
        return modulations;
    }

    public boolean add(DegreeNotation notation, @Nullable Interval modulationInterval) {
        degreeNotations.add(notation);
        if (modulationInterval != null) {
            modulations.put(degreeNotations.size() - 1, modulationInterval);
        }
        return true;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Progression clone() {
        Progression clone = null;
        try {
            clone = (Progression) super.clone();
            
            clone.progressionId = this.progressionId;

            // ArrayListのディープコピー
            List<DegreeNotation> notationsList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (DegreeNotation notation : degreeNotations) {
                notationsList.add(notation.clone());
            }
            clone.degreeNotations = notationsList;

            clone.functions = new ArrayList<>(functions);

            clone.tags = new ArrayList<>(tags);

            clone.notes = new ArrayList<>(notes);

            // HashMap のディープコピー
            Map<Integer, Interval> deepCopiedMap = new HashMap<>();
            for (Map.Entry<Integer, Interval> entry: modulations.entrySet()) {
                deepCopiedMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().clone());
            }

            // こちらも不可
            // Map<Integer, Interval> deepCopiedMap = new HashMap<>(modulations);

            clone.modulations = deepCopiedMap;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return clone;
    }
```

クローンを使用するメソッド(別クラス)

```
public void addModulation(Interval interval) {

        Progression clone = progression.clone();
        // まだ増えていない
        Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "addModulation() clone.modulations.size():" + clone.modulations.size());
        // true ... なぜか同じ参照になっている？
        Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "addModulation() clone.modulations == progression.modulations : " + (clone.modulations == progression.modulations));
        // false ... ArrayList メンバは新しいインスタンスを参照できている
        Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "addModulation() clone.degreeNotations == progression.degreeNotations : " + (clone.degreeNotations == progression.degreeNotations));

        // 履歴に追加
        history.push(clone);

        Map<Integer, Interval> modulations = progression.getModulations();
        if (modulations.containsKey(focus)) {
            modulations.replace(focus, interval);
        } else {
            modulations.put(focus - 1, interval);
        }
        Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "addModulation() modulations.size:" + progression.modulations.size());

        // この時点でクローンの HashMap のサイズも増えている？
        Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "addModulation() clone.size:" + clone.modulations.size());
        // 増えている？
        Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "addModulation() history.peek().modulations.size:" + history.peek().modulations.size());
    }
```

Comment: 自己解決おめでとうございます。このサイトでは回答を回答欄に書くことが推奨されています。(質問欄に回答を書くと第三者が解決済みかどうか一目で分からないため)。お時間のあるときに追記内容を回答として再投稿し、回答を承認していただきたく思います。

Comment: この度はご指摘ありがとうございます。投稿ルールをよく分かっておりませんでした。次回から気を付けます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

改めてログ出力をよく見直していたところ、HashMap をコピーする前の

clone.functions = new ArrayList<>(functions);

のところで何かしらのエラーが出ており、それによってそれより後の処理自体がされていなかったことがわかりました。
HashMap のコピー処理をこれよりも前に移動するとうまくいきました。

大変初歩的なミスでお騒がせしてしまい申し訳ございませんでした。